# Can't get JSON file to parse into TableView in JavaScript using Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm trying to get a JSON file into a table in JavaScript using Appcelerator and I'm not quite sure why it is outputting as an empty table when compiling to an example page. I'm rather new to dealing with both JavaScript and JSON formats, so if you see any silly logical or syntax mistakes, please go easy on me and also let me know how I can fix my issue:

```
// Set the background color with no windows or tabs
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');

// Create the window
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Challenge Window',
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
});

// Store the image and its properties
    var image = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    image: "https://myavantiservices.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/helloworld.gif",
    height: 380,
    width: 380,
    center: 512,
    top: -50
});

var tableData;

// Parse our JSON file using onload
var url = "https://www.sitepoint.com/twitter-json-example/";
var json;
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function() {
        json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        tableData = json;
    }
});

// Create the table and insert the JSON data
var table = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    data: tableData,
    height: 480,
    width: 480,
    top: 256,
    left: 232
});

// Add the image to the window and open the window
win1.add(image);
win1.add(table);
win1.open();
```

The JSON returned by the url:

```
    {"results":[

     {"text":"@twitterapi  https://code.google.com/archive/p/twitter-api/issues/353",

     "to_user_id":396524,

     "to_user":"TwitterAPI",

     "from_user":"jkoum",

     "metadata":

     {

      "result_type":"popular",

      "recent_retweets": 109



     },

     "id":1478555574,   

     "from_user_id":1833773,

     "iso_language_code":"nl",

     "source":"twitter< /a>",

     "profile_image_url":"http://s3.amazonaws.com/twitter_production/profile_images/118412707/2522215727_a5f07da155_b_normal.jpg",

     "created_at":"Wed, 08 Apr 2009 19:22:10 +0000"},

     ... truncated ...],

     "since_id":0,

     "max_id":1480307926,

     "refresh_url":"?since_id=1480307926&q=%40twitterapi",

     "results_per_page":15,

     "next_page":"?page=2&max_id=1480307926&q=%40twitterapi",

     "completed_in":0.031704,

     "page":1,

     "query":"%40twitterapi"}

    }
```

Comment: No, no console errors when compiling.

Comment: Not at compilation time, I mean in the Developer Tools in your browser :)

Comment: Oh, sorry. Nope no errors in Chrome either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move everything that relies on the JSON response to be inside of the `onload` block. Otherwise, the table will be constructed before `tableData` has any data. You also aren't actually sending the `xhr`.

Once you get a URL that actually returns that JSON, you can use this:

```
var url = "https://www.sitepoint.com/twitter-json-example/";
var json;
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function() {
        json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        tableData = json;

        var table = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
            data: tableData,
            height: 480,
            width: 480,
            top: 256,
            left: 232
        });

        win1.add(image);
        win1.add(table);
        win1.open();
    }
});
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.send();
```

Comment: I don't think this is the solution. When I try to do this, my window doesn't even form in the browser, I'm just left with a black screen

Comment: Also, I think with your edit on my post, I may have found where my problem might lie. The url I am using has an example of a return JSON file, but the address itself doesn't return a JSON file. https://www.sitepoint.com/twitter-json-example/

Comment: I've updated my answer. I noticed that you weren't actually sending the `xhr` with the `url`. And yes, you will need to use a URL that actually has the data you want.

Comment: still not working unfortunately :/. Perhaps I am missing something fundamental with the way Appcelerator compiles into the browser?

Comment: I uploaded the file to here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/44castle/testing-json/master/jsontest.json Try it out?

Comment: I tried it out, and that'll definitely work for using `JSON.parse` in the `onload` function, but using your code I'm still getting nothing but a black screen.

Comment: Try putting log statements everywhere, to see which code is executing and to see what some of your variables hold.

Comment: Appcelerator does not print out anything to the console when using `console.log()`. Not sure why, but I know that it is an annoyance to those who use the IDE.

Comment: If you can't log, you might have to get creative. Maybe you could change the background color in different places so that you know if the `onload` block is running?

Comment: Ah okay, maybe the problem is I changed a little bit of the original JSON syntax when initially trying to put it into JavaScript since I was getting syntax errors. I re-edited my question so that the JSON file is now exact

Answer (score 0):

Jodo, you really need to read documentations on using [HTTP Client](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient) & [Set Data on TableView](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView).

There is a very clean example in the docs of [Titanium's Working With Remote Data](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Working_with_JSON_Data)

The url you are using is not returning anything other than the HTML output for that website, and secondly you can't simply set data property on tableview unless your data variable is formatted in one of this way.

`[ {title: 'Apples'}, {title: 'Bananas'}, {title: 'Carrots'}, {title: 'Potatoes'} ];`

Moreover, TableView's data property takes an array of Rows/Sections or a well-formatted dictionary. See this for more [TableView Guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/TableViews)

We suggest you to please read the documentation before trying anything if you have not done that ever before. It will help you learn & understand better and definitely will save your precious time. :) Thanks